# aoColumnDefs vs fnRowCallback which is better and faster

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a use case where I want to render a anchor link on specific column index. It can achieved using both fnRowCallback and aoColumnDefs.

So I am wondering which one is better and faster.

Code snippets for both the cases :

**aoColumnDefs**

```
 "aoColumnDefs": [ 
{
    "fnRender": function ( oObj ) {
     return '<a href="abc.html">' + oObj.aData[8]+ '</a>';
     },
    "aTargets": [8]
},
]
```

**fnRowCallback**

```
"fnRowCallback" : function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull ) {

$("td:eq(8)", nRow).html('<a  href="abc.html">' + aData[8]+ '</a>'
);}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe with the newest builds of datatables fnRender is deprecated , you should be using mData and mRender

mRender is preferred for use over FnRowCallback on server-side implementations to create urls from data

here is an example, add it to aoColumns for the field, and remove the FnRowCallback

```
  { "mData": null , 
    "mRender" : function ( data, type, full ) {
    return '<a href="abc.html">'+full[8]+'</a>';}
  },
```

Docs: http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/advanced_init/column_render.html

Comment: mRender is more like aoColumnDefs. But i think fnRowCallback gives you more flexibility. With aoColumnDefs and mRender a single theme would be applied across all rows. But fnRowCallBack puts the control per row at users hand

Comment: in regards to the question, putting an anchor link per row, docs say best way is to use mRender, however i do agree with you that if you need to say evaluate data on a per row basis , then do an action (like  adding a grade color type based on row/column value) then fnRowCallback is preferred...i use both where the situation dictates